# Using "how" for number of bits (in a digital system)

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

In an article, I need to use a short expression for "a system with a high number of bits". I mean for example a system of 10 bits instead of 4 bits. How I can use a short and accurate expression. Can I use:

(1) high number bits system,
(2) high-number bits system

or maybe a better short expression is recommended.

Comment: I might go for something like "high bit count". The alternatives you suggest seem pretty awkward.

Comment: In a 10-bit system as opposed to a 4-bit system are the additional bits used to increase the resolution of the system (smaller LSB value) or increase the range of the system (larger MSB value)?

Comment: you should provide a very short description of the designed system.

Comment: The precision needed requires a larger bit count. That might be one with Greater Resolution.

Comment: Thank you. I think the phrase "high bit count" matches more with the concept that I explained. Can I use "high-bit count" or "higher bit count" as well?